# How to include table in linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

There are two tables: KindergartenIssues_Users and Users. Now I'm getting fileds of first table.However I could not get full name of user by UserId from 'Users' table.

I got data from 'Kindergartenissues_Users' table. How to correctly write incude to get full name by foreign key of UserId field?

```cs
public static async Task<List<KindergartenIssues_UsersView>> GetKinderGartenIssues()
        {
            List<KindergartenIssues_UsersView> users = new List<KindergartenIssues_UsersView>();
            try
            {
                using (var entities = new WebPortalEntities())
                {
                    users = await entities.KindergartenIssues_Users
                        .Where(k => k.DeletedDate == null)
                        .Select(k => new KindergartenIssues_UsersView()
                        {
                            ID = k.ID,
                            UserId = k.UserId,
                            RegDateWithFoundation = k.RegDateWithFoundation,
                            Year = k.Year,
                            AuthorId = k.AuthorId,
                            CreatedDate = k.CreatedDate,
                            ModifiedDate = k.ModifiedDate,
                            EditorId = k.EditorId,
                            DeletedDate = k.DeletedDate,
                            Description = k.Description,
                            ChildBirthYear = k.ChildBirthYear,
                            isHistory = k.isHistory
                        }).ToListAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommonHelper.WriteError($"GetKinderGartenIssues ERROR: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex)}");
            }

            return users;
        }
```

Comment: You should create a new class with all the fields you need from `KindergartenIssues_UsersView` and `Users`, then select from `KindergartenIssues_UsersView` join `Users`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        public static async Task<List<object>> GetKinderGartenIssues()
        {
            try
            {
                var users = new List<object>();
                using (var entities = new WebPortalEntities())
                {
                    users = await entities.KindergartenIssues_Users
                    .Where(k => k.DeletedDate == null)
                    .Join(entities.Users, o => o.UserId, i => i.UserId, (ki, u) => {
// You can obviously define your class somewhere instead of using anonymous object...
                        return new {
                            ID = ki.ID,
                            UserId = ki.UserId,
                            FullName = u.FullName
                            // etc...
                        };
                    }).ToListAsync();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CommonHelper.WriteError($"GetKinderGartenIssues ERROR: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex)}");
            }

            return users;
        }
```